# An explicit correspondence for reductions of modular curves $Y(N)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, modular-forms, algebraic-curves

Let $Y(N)$ be the modular curve associated with the principal congruence subgroup $\Gamma(N) \subset \mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$ of level $N \in \mathbb{N}$. It is well known that this curve has a plane affine model over a quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Consider its reduction $Y_p(N) \subset \mathbb{A}^{\!2}_{x,\,y}$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$, where $p$ is a prime, $p \nmid N$. We know that points of $Y_p(N)(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p})$ correspond (up to an isomorphism) to triples $(E, P, Q)$, where $E$ is an elliptic curve over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ and $P$, $Q$ form a basis of the $N$-torsion subgroup $E[N]$. Finally, under this correspondence all triples with supersingular elliptic curves belong $Y_p(N)(\mathbb{F}_{p^2})$.

Is there a way to explicitly compute a bijective map between points of $Y_p(N)$ (pairs (x, y) satisfying some modular equation) and triples $(E, P, Q)$? May be, is there a birational map between $Y_p(N)$ and the curve
$$V = \big\{ \big(j, \pi_j(P, Q)\big) \mid P,Q {\rm \ form \ a \ basis \ of \ } E[N] \big\}?$$
Here $K_{j}$ is the Kummer surface for the direct square $E_{j}^2$ of the elliptic curve $E_j$ with $\mathrm{j}$-invariant $j$ and $\pi_j\!: E_{j}^2 \to K_j$ is the natural $2$-sheeted covering associated with the involution $[-1]$ on $E_j^2$.

Comment: I am not sure I know what you mean by the question. What is given to you and what do you want? Are you just looking for a model of this curve over $\mathbb{Z}[1/N]$ ?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: This doesn't quite work as stated (because there's not a unique elliptic curve with a given $j$-invariant unless the base field is alg. closed) but something quite similar to this will work. I strongly recommend the article by Rohrlich in the Cornell--Silverman--Stevens book "Modular forms and Fermat's last theorem" which gives a beautiful and accessible account of how models for modular curves are constructed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at the paper (sorry for the autocite)

F. Bars, A. Kontogeorgis and X. Xarles, Bielliptic and hyperelliptic modular curves X(N) and the group Aut(X(N)). Acta Arith. 161 (2013), 283-299 ([eudml](https://eudml.org/doc/278915), [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.2273))

specially lemma 1, where some relations with several other well-known modular curves is stated.